# Here matrix routing return failed if we combine 2 particular waypoints

Tags: here-api

We make a request to the matrix (version 7.2) but we have a failed when we combine some waypoints with others. This request returns a response time for both waypoints.

Request:

```
https://matrix.route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculatematrix.json?app_id=[APP_ID]&app_code=[APP_CODE]&start0=53.749313,-107.732895&destination0=49.52757,-115.75541&destination1=50.47252,-104.57122&mode=shortest;car;traffic:enabled;&summaryAttributes=tt,di
```

Response:

```
{
    "response": {
        "metaInfo": {
            "timestamp": "2020-04-30T13:36:03Z",
            "mapVersion": "8.30.108.151",
            "moduleVersion": "7.2.202017-6962",
            "interfaceVersion": "2.6.76",
            "availableMapVersion": ["8.30.108.151"]
        },
        "matrixEntry": [{
            "startIndex": 0,
            "destinationIndex": 0,
            "summary": {
                "distance": 1070433,
                "travelTime": 48713,
                "costFactor": 326105
            }
        }, {
            "startIndex": 0,
            "destinationIndex": 1,
            "summary": {
                "distance": 487523,
                "travelTime": 19223,
                "costFactor": 147460
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

If we change the second waypoint, the routing for the first waypoint returns a failed instead of time and distance.

Request:

```
https://matrix.route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculatematrix.json?app_id=[APP_ID]&app_code=[APP_CODE]&start0=53.749313,-107.732895&destination0=49.52757,-115.75541&destination1=51.23123,-102.47058&mode=shortest;car;traffic:enabled;&summaryAttributes=tt,di
```

Response:

```
{
    "response": {
        "metaInfo": {
            "timestamp": "2020-04-30T13:52:00Z",
            "mapVersion": "8.30.108.151",
            "moduleVersion": "7.2.202017-6962",
            "interfaceVersion": "2.6.76",
            "availableMapVersion": ["8.30.108.151"]
        },
        "matrixEntry": [{
            "startIndex": 0,
            "destinationIndex": 0,
            "status": "failed"
        }, {
            "startIndex": 0,
            "destinationIndex": 1,
            "summary": {
                "distance": 541091,
                "travelTime": 26209,
                "costFactor": 165129
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Anyone have any idea why?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please try changing to following modes, they are giving correct response for car profiles. However for shortest;car mode which should be working, is returning failure, we will checking that with our internal engineering team.

https://matrix.route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculatematrix.json?app_id=xxx&app_code=xxx&start0=geo!53.749313,-107.732895&destination0=geo!49.52757,-115.75541&destination1=geo!51.23123,-102.47058&mode=fastest;car;traffic:enabled

**Traffic-enabled:**

mode=fastest;car;traffic:enabled

**Traffic not enabled:**

mode=fastest;car;traffic:disabled

Comment: Thanks. I try "fastest" already and it's working as you say but some of our clients need there route in "shortest" mode, that's why.